# Oracle Query to retrieve only first & last name from a column using Case statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need to write a oracle sql query using CASE Statement for the below.

The table “employee” contains columns: EID and Name with 4 values.

[image: Table and columns]

**Below is Excepted Output with a new column "F_L_Name":**

The middle initials and “Doctor” word in the last row has to be removed.

The format of the Doctor name is " Last Name, First Name , Initial). Please help me in achieving the below new column using CASE.

[image: Smith, Mary Koch, J Batoon Rene, Anne Vaughan-tre, Maria]

Comment: Why can you have the surname "Batoon Rene" but not "Vaughan-tre Doctor"?

Comment: You cannot do this using a `CASE` expression; you would need to use string functions (`SUBSTR`, `INSTR`, `REGEXP_REPLACE` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR`). But the best solution is not to need to do it in the first place by having separate columns for `first_name`, `last_name`, `title` and `middle_initials` and then if you want to **display** only the `last_name, first_name` then it only requires simple string concatenation rather than trying to apply fuzzy rules to work out if the `last_name` is "lord doctor" or "lord" or if they have two titles and no last name.

Comment: Sometimes users enter "Doctor" keyword specifying the title of that person.  In this example, Vaghan-tre, Maria S is a Doctor. However, while retrieving the new column, we need to remove that keyword

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Doctor can be a last name. Not very common, but entirely possible. Are you going to ASSUME that Doctor is always an appellation, and not a last name? (Even if it appears by itself as the last name?) Then - if you must handle Doctor that way, what other such keywords should be handled the same way?

Comment: Doctor is the only keyword and appellation that needs to be handled at this point  of time.